# How do I get GPS to get my co-ordinates every time I click the button?

Tags: objective-c, camera, gps

I'm creating an app that allows a user to take a picture and receive GPS co-ordinates that coincide with the pictures location, displayed in a label in the cameraView. The picture, time/date and GPS location is then transferred to another view for the user to put a title and description and allows them to save the event. A pop-up alerts them it was saved, and when they click save, the view transfers back to the camera view, where the fields are now clear and ready for the next picture.
My issue is that when the user goes back to the camera view, or even stays on the first view and wants to take multiple pictures, no more GPS co-ordinates are put in the label? I can't figure out why. It's like it only can happen once?

I set the cameraView up so when the user clicks the button, coordinates are retrieved every time?

Here is my mainView.h file on the first controller

//labels for the camera view values
    IBOutlet UILabel *DateTimeText;

```
IBOutlet UILabel *LongitudeText;
IBOutlet UILabel *LatitudeText;

NSData *image;
NSData *passBackImage;



 Here is the mainView.m file



//When the user hits the "take a picture button"
-(IBAction)onMoreSnapsClick:(id)sender{


 UIImagePickerController *pickerControl = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

// If all's good, start up the camera
    if (pickerControl != nil)
       {
          pickerControl.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
          pickerControl.delegate = self;
          pickerControl.allowsEditing = true;


    // Camera turns on
    [self presentViewController:pickerControl animated:true completion:nil];


    //Retrieve co-ordinates when picture is taken
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    //Format date
    _date = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [_date setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];


    //Date into a string
    _dateString = [_date stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [self->DateTimeText setText:_dateString];

    [_date stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    //Update the location
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];        

   }
   } 


   - (NSString*) getDateTime

      {
       NSDateFormatter *formatter;


       formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];

       _dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

       return _dateString;
      }

      //Setting up the delegate for the location finder

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
      {
          NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
         UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"            

          delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [errorAlert show];
       }

       - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:            
      (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
        {
           NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
           CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;


   _snapLatitude =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];


 _snapLongitude =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];


           if (currentLocation != nil) {

               LongitudeText.text = _snapLatitude;
               LatitudeText.text = _snapLongitude;


         }


        }


           //Also attached to my button-clears the fields of the previous picture coords                                         
       -(IBAction)onClick:(UIButton*)sender
           {

             DateTimeText.text = nil;
             LongitudeText.text =nil;
             LatitudeText.text = nil;
             _cameraMainView = nil;
           } 

       //Creating the objects for the images

  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerControl 

           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

       {
       //When finished, access the stored images
        _cameraMainView = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

         image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_cameraMainView);

    // if everything's okay......
             if (_cameraMainView != nil)

    // assign the images to the properties
        {
          _imageView.image = _cameraMainView;

    // allow editing and create the delegate
           pickerControl.delegate = self;
           pickerControl.allowsEditing = true;

       }



[pickerControl dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];


  }


   -(IBAction)snapsDetails:(id)sender
  {


       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"snapSegue" sender:self];


  }


  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
     {

         if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"snapSegue"])
     {
           SnapAddTextViewController *toSnapView = segue.destinationViewController;

              toSnapView.timeDate = _dateString;
              toSnapView.snapViewLongitude = _snapLongitude;
              toSnapView.snapViewLatitude =_snapLatitude;
              toSnapView.snapActualImage =[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:image];



}
```

}

Can someone tell me why it will only takes one set of coordinates with the first picture taken and none after that? I am still in school and appreciate the leniency on code structure and neatness.I usually pretty it up as things fall together correctly, thanks.a

Comment: Put NSLog's in your LocationManager delegate methods or add breakpoints to check the values.

Comment: Thank you Jasper Pol. My info is coming through the 1st time my user takes a pic and puts the coords into the fields and I'm able to deliver that info to my secondView through a segue. I've set breakpoints on my segue and all the info is there. It's just every time AFTER that 1st picture, the coords aren't being delivered to the label and there isn't a way that I know of to set a break point on the 2nd clicking of a button. My date/time show up every button click. Is the problem  my onClick where I remove the last values from the fields with nil...does this nil action remove them permanently?

Comment: What is the difference between the actions 'onMoreSnapsClick' and 'onClick'. Which is called when? If you nil the text of a UILabel it will be empty until you set a new text. It does not mean you cannot enter a new value anymore.

Comment: Is see you have a log in your LocationManager delegate method 'NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);'. Does he actually give you a value there the 2nd time you want to take a picture?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I had the location manager initializing on view did load. I moved it into the onMoreSnapsClick. Now it initializes cllocation every time the user takes a pic, and puts the correct values in the fields. Thanks for offering assistance Jasper Pol! I hope this helps other people who have this issue.